# How to use the past perfect construction correctly?

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

Do the following sentences make sense in terms of tenses?
(Or how do I make the tenses right?)

1. When the man ***was*** hit by a truck, it ***took*** two hours before he ***was*** successfully resuscitated.
2. When the man ***had been*** hit by a truck, it took two hours before he was successfully resuscitated.
3. When the man was hit by a truck, it took two hours before he ***had been*** successfully resuscitated.
4. When the man was hit by a truck, it ***had taken*** two hours before he was successfully resuscitated.

Comment: Clue: The past perfect is used to show that one action **precedes** another. So, now you can figure it out for yourself. **I had finished when he arrived**. See?

Answer (score 1):

We seldom use the past perfect tense where time markers make clear the sequence of events

> After she gave birth to twins, her whole life changed radically

> After she had given birth to twins, her whole life changed radically

Both are grammatical, but the first is more common because "after" sufficiently explains the sequence.

On that basis, sentences 1 and 2 are grammatical, but sentence 2 is not at all idiomatic because the temporal sequence is reasonably clear without the past perfect. Nor is sentence 1 completely idiomatic. The word "after" is more apt than "when."

> After the man was hit by the truck, it took two hours before he was successfully resuscitated.

With "after" and "before" in the sentence, the temporal sequence is perfectly clear without resort to the past perfect.

A style point and so opinion. It is a contradiction in terms to be unsuccessfully resuscitated. So it would be better style in my opinion to write

> before he was resuscitated